# DevExpress: ASPxGridView cell editing on client side events

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to edit particular column in ASPxGridView using client side event.

Just i getting index value like that:

```
function onRowclick(s,e)
{
    e.VisibleIndex;
    ...

}
```

I am not sure how to open grid column in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

This will start editing clicked row:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" ...>
    <ClientSideEvents RowClick="function(s, e) {
        s.StartEditRow(e.visibleIndex);
    }" />
...
```

If you want to edit only one column, make other columns readonly.

Documentation:
[ASPxClientGridView.RowClick event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_RowClicktopic)
[ASPxClientGridView.StartEditRow method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_StartEditRowtopic)
[GridViewColumn.ReadOnly property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataColumn_ReadOnlytopic)